# How to get event when text goes to new line?

Tags: jquery

Is there any event in jQuery when on 'text' goes to a new line.

I need to show a alert box when a text goes to new line in jQuery?

Here is my fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/rgeHe/

```
   setInterval(function () {
       $('#realTimeContents').append("Hiiiii. is div")
   }, 1000);
```

Comment: There's nothing native that does exactly what you want. I'm not sure I would go with setInterval here. I think binding to the keypress event on your element might make more sense, and then checking to see if the height has changed.

Answer (score 5):

How about checking the height of the div on each interval?

```
$(function() {
  var h = -1;
  setInterval(function () {
    var newHeight = $('#realTimeContents').append("Hiiiii. is div").height();
    if(h == -1) h = newHeight;
    if(h != newHeight) {
        h = newHeight;
        alert("I've changed height");
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/TnTj9/) is a fork of your fiddle.

Comment: I need to show a alert if there is new line every time .can you change on fiddle

Comment: Updated answer to include fiddle

Comment: can you solve my one more issue in jquery/jquery mobile ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270010/caching-issue-in-android-using-jquery-mobile